# Implementing tridiagonal matrix algorithm (TDMA) with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

I'm implementing TDMA in Python using NumPy. The tridiagonal matrix is stored in three arrays:

```
a = array([...])
b = array([...])
c = array([...])
```

I'd like to calculate `alpha`-coefficients efficiently. The algorithm is as follows:

```
# n = size of the given matrix - 1
alpha = zeros(n)
alpha[0] = b[0] / c[0]
for i in range(n-1):
    alpha[i+1] = b[i] / (c[i] - a[i] * alpha[i])
```

However, this is not efficient because of Python's `for` loop. Want I want is something like this approach:

```
# n = size of the given matrix - 1
alpha = zeros(n)
alpha[0] = b[0] / c[0]
alpha[1:] = b[1:] / (c[1:] - a[1:] * alpha[:-1])
```

In this latter case the result is incorrect because NumPy stores the right part of the last expression in a temprorary array and then assigns references to its elements to `alpha[1:]`. Therefore `a[1:] * alpha[:-1]` is just an array of zeros.

Is there a way to tell NumPy to use values of `alpha` calculated on previous steps within its internal loop?

Thanks.

Comment: this isn't possible.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587367/python-numpy-tricky-slicing-problem for a similar issue.  if you really need the speed increase, try cython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there is no way to do this in Python without using C or its *pythonic* variations.

Answer (score 2):

If its tridiagonal systems you want to solve there is `solve_banded()` in `numpy.linalg`. Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: i don't think there is any provision for banded matrix solving , in numpy or even in scipy , there is no sp.sparse ,as far as i know.

Comment: I think it's my bad , scipy.sparse exists(it doesn't exist on my system , it existsin docs so it must actually exist) , but not solve_banded() in numpy.linalg , may have been when present in 2009 , not now.